# Can I parse C functions with a regular expression in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have an application written on **C#**. In this application want to parse **C source code files** and get functions with their body. I've created the regular expression:

```
([a-zA-z]+)(\s)([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-z0-9]+)(\({1})(.*)(\){1})(\n|\r)*(\{{1})(.|\n|\r)+(\}{1})[^\n]
```

But it doesn't work correctly. For example, these two functions passed the controll like it was one function:

```
void setTargetToCollisionBuffer(SDL_Renderer *ren)
{
    if (SDL_SetRenderTarget(ren, collision_buffer) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to switch Target to collision_buffer");
    }
}

void setTargetToBuffer(SDL_Renderer *ren)
{
    if (SDL_SetRenderTarget(ren, buffer) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to switch Target to buffer");
    }
}
```

Please, help to improve the reg. expression! Or maybe you know some other ways to parse **C source code files** in **C#**? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't do that.  You need a real parser.

Comment: Although you want to parse a [tag:c] function this question doesn't relate to the [tag:c] language in a way that including the [tag:c] tag is necessary.

Comment: @iharob, thank you for making my question more clear for other people

Comment: This is simply not possible. To grab each function at the very least you need a good parser that knows how to handle comments, string literals, character literals, etc. So no, not possible with just a regular expression.

Comment: @SLaks I couldn't find a parser that helped me in this situation. Can you offer something?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't need ti know, what is inside of function. I just want to have smth like that: void foo(arguments){smth inside the brackets}

Comment: I have seen some technique to parse such texts with C# regex. The techique is based on using `\G` at the start and then named capture groups that match tokens inside an alternation group. Still, that is rather cumbersome and rather error prone.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks a lot! I'll try to check ANTLR

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to lock this question. Since the answers in the redirected question have 404s all over the place. Nice job!